# How to propagate WHERE condition down to all joined tables?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I'm working on a project with a MySQL database. I have some CTEs that summarize features of the users (each CTE summarizes one feature). Then I have a last query that joins all other CTEs on a column named user_id.

The following example describes this well (note that the actual problem is more complex and this is just a way to explain it in a clear way):

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE  TABLE scores (
   user_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   score int(3) default NULL,
   CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`)
);
```

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU1lg.png)

[scores table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAr8S.png)

```sql
with
    avg_score_by_user as (
        select 
            user_id,
            avg(score) as avg_score
        from
            scores
        group by user_id
    ),
    
    max_score_by_user as (
        select
            user_id,
            max(score) as max_score
        from
            scores
        group by user_id
    )
    
    select
        users.user_id,
        avg_score_by_user.avg_score,
        max_score_by_user.max_score
    from
        users
    join
        avg_score_by_user
    on
        avg_score_by_user.user_id = users.user_id
    join
        max_score_by_user
    on
        max_score_by_user.user_id = users.user_id;
```

In my use case, I use this to query the features of a specific user. To do that I do `where user_id=1`  (or some other id) at the end of the query.

The problem is that this outer where (user_id=1) does not propagate to all joined CTEs. I haven't found a proof in MySQL's docs but according to some sources (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch04.html under "Equality propagation") and some Googling, the `where user_id=1` condition should propagate to `max_score_by_user` and `avg_score_by_user` so that the filtering happens early on those CTEs instead of happening on the whole result set.

To clarify this problem, we can look at the `explain`  of the query:

[Explain of the CTE query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xeoJ.png)

You can see that both CTEs (the DERIVED tables) scan all 6 rows where they should scan only 3 each as these are the rows corresponding to `user_id=1`.

Interestingly, if we filter using `where avg_score_by_user.user_id=1`, the optimization does happen and `avg_score_by_user` scans only 3 rows but `max _score_by_user` still scans 6 rows:

[Explain of the CTE query with different where condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnPiY.png)

Bottom line, I would want the where `users.user_id=1` to happen early in each CTE so that each CTE scans only the relevant rows for that user.

I tried using the `using(user_id)` instead of the `on` clause but still did not work.

Comment: *I use this to query the features of a specific user. To do that I do where user_id=1 (or some other id) at the end of the query.* If the query shown is real one then CTEs makes no sense. You may filter by the user then aggregate w/o GROUP BY.

Comment: Right, I should have stated that the tables in the question are used only as an example. The actual query in my project is more complex. I'll make that more clear in the question, thanks!

Comment: It's my experience that recent MySQL and MariaDB versions' query planners handle queries with CTEs and/or VIEWs as if they were nested subqueries. I know for sure that it doesn't make sense to extrapolate from the query plan for a CTE to a query plan for a larger query. Examine the query plans for your actual queries.

Comment: You have two separate aggregate CTEs that process precisely the same set of rows with the same GROUP BY. For best performance you should combine those into one, and not rely on the query planner to figure out it only needs to aggregate those rows once.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `WHERE` condition to the CTEs. But, in your case, the CTEs are not needed at all. You will get the same result with:

```
select
    s.user_id,
    avg(s.score) as avg_score,
    max(s.score) as max_score,
from scores s
group by s.user_id
```

Comment: Right, I should have stated that the tables in the question are used only as an example. The actual query in my project is more complex.
Regarding adding the WHERE condition to the CTE, I need this WHERE to be generic as I don't always use the same user_id

Answer (score 0):

> In my use case, I use this to query the features of a specific user. To do that I do where user_id=1 (or some other id) at the end of the query.

```
SELECT user_id,
       AVG(scores.score) AS avg_score,
       MAX(scores.score) AS max_score
FROM users
JOIN scores USING (user_id)
WHERE user_id = 1
-- or
-- WHERE user_id IN ( {user_id list} )
-- GROUP BY user_id
;
```

---

If your query is more complex, and shown query is a pattern, then you may do the next trick:

```
WITH 
parameter AS (
    SELECT {needed user_id} AS user_id
    ),
cte1 AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    JOIN parameter USING (user_id)
    ),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    JOIN parameter USING (user_id)
    ),
...

SELECT ...
FROM ...
JOIN cte1 USING (user_id)
JOIN cte2 USING (user_id)
...
```

Alternatively you may assign your parameter value into the user-defined variable in the most first CTE then use it in WHERE instead of CTE joining.

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE user_id = ( @user_id := {needed user_id} )
    ),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE user_id = @user_id
    ),
...

SELECT ...
FROM ...
JOIN cte1 USING (user_id)
JOIN cte2 USING (user_id)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a "derived table", then `JOIN` to `users` to get other data.

```
SELECT  users.user_id,
        users.name
    FROM (
       select
           s.user_id,
           avg(s.score) as avg_score,
           max(s.score) as max_score,
       from scores s
       group by s.user_id
          ) AS agg
    JOIN users  ON agg.user_id = users.user_id;
```

Comment: `<snide-comment-for-the-day>`Yet again, the addition of `WITH` to MySQL leads novices to use it unnecessarily.`</snide-comment-for-the-day>`